# checking version doesn't seem to work with Python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, compatibility

I'm revising some python and as such wrote this little program but it looks like `sys.version_info[0]` doesn't seem to work with Python2 and gives me an error

The program:

```
import sys
import pdb

pdb.set_trace()

method = "first"
print "This is the " + method + " way to print stuff\n"

method = "second"
print ("This is the " + method + " way to print stuff\n")

method = "third"
print ("This is the ", method, " way to print stuff\n")

if (sys.version_info[0] > 2):
    method = "fourth"
    print(f"This is the {method} way to print stuff")
```

The error it throws is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py",
>   line 1314, in main
>       pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
>       self.run(statement)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
>       exec cmd in globals, locals   File "", line 1, in    File "WaysToPrint.py", line 17
>       print(f"This is the {method} way to print stuff")

What could be wrong? How to go about this?

Comment: f-strings simply didn't exist in Python 2.x, or early versions of 3.x - your script will fail to compile, even though the offending code wouldn't actually get executed.  Note that you could never reach that part of the program anyway on 3.x, as that first `print` (with no parentheses) would be a syntax error.

Comment: Oh OK. So these `f-strings` are NOT even recognized by the older interpreters then it looks. So no way to use them in code that's meant to be backward compatible.
And yes I did see that those print statements without brackets would fail on 3.x